# Inserting HTML5 video using JavaScript for iPad

Tags: jquery, video, ipad, html

I am trying to insert a video into HTML using jQuery for iPad but all I see is a black screen. If I add the video tag directly to the HTML page all seems to work fine.

Here is what I have in my JavaScript and I call this using a function for onClick event.

```
var html = "";
html += '<video id="someVideo" width="'+settings.width+'" height="'+settings.height+'" controls="controls">';
html += '<source src="'+url+'"  type="video/mp4" />';
html += '</video>';
$("#videoDiv").html(html);
```

If I create a video tag right inside the body everything seems to be working fine

```
<video width=708px height=300px controls="controls"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

The reason I am planning a JavaScript is that I have few videos on the same page and wanted the user to select a video to be viewed as oppose to a single video on a page... Any idea around that will also help

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 19):

There is a bug in iPad's webkit that prevents dynamically created video elements from loading properly.

To get around this set the source attribute and call the video elements load method after you have set the html

```
var html = "";
html += '<video id="someVideo" width="'+settings.width+'" height="'+settings.height+'" controls="controls">';
html += '<source src="'+url+'"  type="video/mp4" />';
html += '</video>';
$("#videoDiv").html(html);

$('#someVideo').attr('src', url);
$('#someVideo')[0].load();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Somewhat shorter and more generic, I ended up doing this: `$('video').each(function() {
              var el = $(this)[0];
              $(this).replaceWith(el.outerHTML);
              el.load();
            });` - seems to achieve the same effect

Comment: This worked for me as well.  BTW, my video wasn't showing in ie9 either.  With ampt's solution video is now playing in both browsers.

Comment: anybody know when this was fixed? in ios7 this problem isn't apparent anymore (I'm using jQuery mobile which dynamically loads pages)

Answer (score 2):

Re ampts answer: please note calling load() on the video element only works if your code is triggered by a user action, like a click handler.

For me this didn't work as apple doesn't seem to think that the history handler (hash change) is a user triggered handler.

For more details [see apples documentation on javascript and the video element](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I am planning a JavaScript
>   is that I have few videos on the same
>   page and wanted the user to select a
>   video to be viewed as oppose to a
>   single video on a page... Any idea
>   around that will also help

Place all the videos on the page, each with a style "display: none".  Then .show() the appropriate div on the click event.

Comment: Will this prevent all the videos from precaching?