# vimeo videos autoplay after load()

Tags: jquery, video, iframe, vimeo, autoplay

I'm using this solution to load iframe containing vimeo videos on ipad and PC web browsers
[how to control apple video player on ipad (video embeded with iframe and html5 vimeo solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032461/how-to-control-apple-video-player-on-ipad-video-embeded-with-iframe-and-html5-vi)

It's working well but autoplay is not working on PC web browsers.
Do you have solution to autoplay Vimeo videos once the iframe containing the video is loaded?

adding `&autoplay=1` to video url is not working

adding `&api=1` to video url and `$("#video1").play();` is not working

the solution could be :

1. testing if video is loaded
2. play video with vimeo froogaloop scripts

Answer (score 2):

This is working: autoplay=true

for example: https://player.vimeo.com/video/168478494?autoplay=true